# Why webpack doesn't render CSS from components to vendor.css file?

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack, styles

I use this [template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) It works well. As you can see on the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzZLU.png), all lybrarys (like bootstrap) render their CSS into vendor.css, but my component renders it into html directly, just into the header part in the html file in  tag. Can you tell me how to configure it right?

```
// webpack.config.js

var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;
//var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } },
            { test: /\.(jpg1)$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

and

```
// webpack.config.vendor.js

var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'jquery',
            'zone.js',
            'angular2-modal'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```

Comment: Could you add your `webpack.config.js`? Webpack by default will inject CSS into the head of your page, but if it's already creating a `vendor.css` file then it's just a configuration issue.

Comment: I have added webpack.config.js and webpack.config.vendor.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) to load your component css.  You can change it to be the same loader (most likely file-loader) as the vendor.css in your webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the two css loaders in your config files, you can see that `webpack.config.vendor.js` has this line:

`{ test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }`

under loaders. That is the line that takes the CSS and puts it in its own file. So if you change the CSS loader for your `webpack.config.js` and make sure to add:

`var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'); // or name it whatever you want`

at  the top of the file. It should work.